# How can I open Django app page within the domain name, not like domain/app_page_url?

Tags: django, python-3.x, cpanel

**Python == 3.6.5**

**Django == 1.8**

Recently purchased domain name, *http://www.favourite.uz*. And placed my Django project to my hosting in cPanel. When I browse domain *http://www.favourite.uz*, it throws to default page of cPanel. But when try *http://www.favourite.uz/news* it opens my django app. I wanted to browse this *http://www.favourite.uz/news* page **within** the domain name, without *[/news.](/news)*

I placed used server's namespaces in Domain registrator's page. Tried to create another simple project from this tutorial,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffqMZ5IcmSY. But it still opens default page of cPanel.

Main **favourite/urls.py**

```
# from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

if settings.DEBUG is False:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root' : settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),
    ]
```

(news)app url, **news/urls.py**

```
from . import views

urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^$', views.NewsView.as_view(), name='posts'),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^index', views.search, name="search"),
    url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
    url(r'^league/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.league_detail, name='league_detail'),
]
```

settings, **favourite/settings.py**

```
Django settings for futbik_version_7 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'news/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'news/static/images'),
)
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'az=5ur80-1ge@!951w3(bxaqg1zwo1+a#6+*s*dw(sgkywhb3z'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'www.favourite.uz', 'favourite.uz']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'modeltranslation',
    'news.apps.NewsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_userforeignkey',
    'simplesearch',
    'smart_selects',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_userforeignkey.middleware.UserForeignKeyMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
]

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('Uzbek')),
    ('ru', _('Русский')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

# MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en'
# MODELTRANSLATION_TRANSLATION_REGISTRY = 'news.translation'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'futbik_version_7.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'news/templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'news.context_processors.add_variable_to_context',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'futbik_version_7.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTERS = {
#     'default': 'south.db.sqlite3'
# }

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tashkent'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = False


# MODELTRANSLATION_DEBUG = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/
```

I really appreciate, if someone encountered such situation and helps me to solve this little problem. 
*P.s. I am beginner in Django!*

Comment: You need to give us some information about how you're running Django. Are you using nginx, gunicorn/uwsgi, Apache/mod_wsgi, what?

Comment: Good effort in creating a nicely formulated question! Note: you've exposed the secret_key from your settings file, you should change it soon (and you should never publish it again).

Comment: @DanielRoseman So sorry for stupid question, but how to know this, I really do not know how I am running!

Comment: you don't have a url pattern for the `/` url, but that would throw a 404 page not found. What servers are you using? Something is returning a default cpanel page before it reaches your Django app.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you very much, I changed)

Comment: How did you install django and your app on the server?

Comment: @dirkgroten I installed Django from module section in cPanel interface of  Setup Python App.

Comment: I did this steps: setup python application in cPanel interface -> installed django and modules I used -> uploaded project folder into this application folder. And googling still...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a redirect URL to your urls, so that `/` redirects to `/news`. In *favourite/urls.py*, add this:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

url_patterns = [    
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='posts', permanent=True))  # <—- add this line
]
```

This should work.

I just find it strange that instead of showing a 404 not found, cPanel seems to hijack the missing page. If my method doesn't work, you should contact cPanel support and ask how to enable the default domain to be routed to your app.

Comment: Thank you for the try. I placed this into _favourite/urls.py_ , but still no luck. However, when browsing [favourite.uz/news](http://favourite.uz/news), browser says **Incomplete response received from application**.

Comment: Also I contacted with cPanel administrators, they said "The job is in your code itself, please modify your urls, then try"...

Comment: Then you’ve changed something else. The one line added for the empty URL can’t produce this on `/news/`. It also looks like you should restart your Django app after making changes.

Comment: And you should try to find your application logs. The error logs will tell you much more.